# Same Core Bluetooth snippet - but works only on iPhone SE and not on iPad Pro

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, ios11

I have been struggling for some days with this strange scenario where the following code works well on an iPhone (iOS 11.0.2) but doesn't do anything on an iPad Pro (iOS 11.0.3). The iPad returns the state of central manager and nothing happens after that.

Would be great to find out what went wrong. Any help appreciated! Do point out if this is a bug that has to be reported to Apple.

```
 func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    var alert = true
    let title = "Bluetooth"
    var message = ""
    switch central.state {
    case .poweredOn:
        print("powered ON")
        alert = false
        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)

    default:
        break
    }}

 func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {


if peripheral.identifier.uuidString == deviceDetails.peripheral_UUID.uuidString {

                self.centralManager.stopScan()

                self.myPeripheral = peripheral 
                print("The peripheral is \(myPeripheral)")
                self.myPeripheral.delegate = self 
                self.centralManager.connect(self.myPeripheral, options: nil) //Connecting to the peripheral

        }

/* Commented out as per @Paulw11 's suggestion
        if peripheral.name == deviceDetails.deviceName {
            centralManager.stopScan()
            self.myPeripheral = peripheral 
            self.myPeripheral.delegate = self 
            centralManager.connect(self.myPeripheral, options: nil) 
        }*/
}
```

Comment: Remove the `if` that is checking for device name and see what happens.  To recognise a known peripheral you should use the identifier, not the name.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Paulw11 I did that and it is the same. The iPhone did detect and not the iPad. Updating the code on the question.

Comment: Remove `if peripheral.identifier.uuidString == deviceDetails.peripheral_UUID.uuidString`, do your peripheral? Before checking if it's the same as the target one, check if you see it first.

Comment: I actually see the list of discovered peripherals with "print" when run on iPhone but not on iPad. This is really strange